# node.js server not running

Tags: networking, mac-osx, node.js, osx-snow-leopard

I am trying to learn node.js, but I'm having trouble getting the simple server to run on `localhost:8888`.

Here is the code for server.js:

```
var http = require("http");

http.createServer(function(request, response) {
response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
response.write("Hello World");
response.end();
}).listen(8888);
```

server.js runs without errors, and trying `netstat -an | grep 8888` from terminal returns

```
tcp4       0      0  *.8888                 *.*                    LISTEN
```

However, when I go to localhost:8888 in a browser, it says that it cannot be found.

I've looked at all the related questions, and nothing has worked so far. I've tried different ports, etc. I know that my router blocks incoming traffic on port 8888, but shouldn't that not matter if I'm trying to access it locally? I've run tomcat servers on this port before, for example. Thanks so much for your help!

**node.js version:** v0.6.15 
**OS:** Mac OS 10.6.8

Comment: have you tried http://127.0.0.1:8888 ?